# Draw rectangle with text inside

Tags: c#, wpf, shapes

I want to make an application in which the user could add rectangle with customizable text inside it. The rectangle also can have another rectangles inside. Just as you can see on these picture:

[image: Example]

I read about DrawingVisual, Shapes etc. So far I did it using DrawingVisual + Host, which derivies from FrameworkElement. DrawingVisual has FormattedText field, and list of Children elements; Host maintain drawing all elements.

The main problem is that, everytime user changes text in any child element I need to calculate new coordinates, width, height of all child elements. *Maybe there is any method to do that automatically?*

*Also, DrawingVisual doesn't have any mouse events. So how to make all elements selectable / hoverable? Or should I derive from some other class?*

Later I will post some code...

**EDIT:**

```
public class VisualHost: FrameworkElement
{
    private VisualCollection _children;
    private List<MyElement> _list;

    public VisualHost(List<MyElement> list)
    {
        _children = new VisualCollection(this);
        _list = list;
    }

    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    {
        get { return _children.Count; }
    }

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index >= _children.Count)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }

        return _children[index];
    }

    private void CheckSize(MyElement element)
    {
        double sw = 0;
        double mh = 0;
        if (element.GetChildCount() > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < element.GetChildCount(); i++)
            {
                CheckSize(element.GetChild(i));
                sw += element.GetChild(i).Width;
                mh = Math.Max(mh, element.GetChild(i).Height);
            }
        }
        element.Width = Math.Max(element.Formatted.Width, sw);
        element.Height = element.Formatted.Height + mh;
    }

    private void DrawElement(double top, double left, MyElement element)
    {
        CheckSize(element);

        var context = element.RenderOpen();
        context.DrawRectangle( null, new Pen(Brushes.Black, 2d), new Rect(new Point(left, top), new Size(element.Width, element.Height)));
        context.DrawText(element.Formatted, new Point(left, top));

        top += element.Formatted.Height;
        if (element.GetChildCount() > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < element.GetChildCount(); i++)
            {
                context.DrawRectangle(null, new Pen(Brushes.Black, 2d), new Rect(new Point(left, top), new Size(element.GetChild(i).Width, element.GetChild(i).Height)));
                context.DrawText(element.GetChild(i).Formatted, new  Point(left, top));
                left += element.GetChild(i).Width;
            }
        }
        context.Close();
        _children.Add(element);
    }

    public void Redraw()
    {
        if (_list != null)
        {
            double top = 0, left = 0;
            foreach (MyElement element in _list)
            {
                DrawElement(top, left, element);
                top += element.Height + 10d;
            }
        }
    }
}



public class MyElement: DrawingVisual
{
    private string _text;

    public string Text 
    {
        get { return _text; } 
        set {
            if (_text != value)
            {
                Typeface typeface = new Typeface(new FontFamily("Arial"), FontStyles.Normal, FontWeights.Normal, FontStretches.Normal);
                Formatted = new FormattedText(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, typeface, 12, Brushes.Red);

                _text = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public FormattedText Formatted { get; private set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }

    private List<MyElement> _children;

    public MyElement GetChild(int i)
    {
        if (i < 0 || i >= _children.Count)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
        return _children[i];
    }

    public int GetChildCount()
    {
        return _children.Count;
    }

    public void AddChild(MyElement child)
    {
        _children.Add(child);
    }

    public MyElement(string Text)
    {
        this.Text = Text;
        this._children = new List<MyElement>();
    }

}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _list = new List<MyElement>();
        _list.Add(new MyElement("text"));

        var e = new MyElement("text 2");
        e.AddChild(new MyElement("a"));
        e.AddChild(new MyElement("b"));
        e.AddChild(new MyElement("c"));

        _list.Add(e);

        _host = new VisualHost(_list);
        MyCanvas.Children.Add(_host);
        _host.Redraw();
    }
```

This is my code for now. I wrote it only to check if idea is correct.

Comment: please post your code now.

Answer (score -1):

well I'm not sure if you would like this approach but you can actually do it very simple... I'm thinking maybe you can use blend to create a user control and design a label and a listbox in a stackpanel and set 'em all on autosizing.
or design 2 stack panels set 1 to do vertical orientation and the other one to do horizontal and add textblocks or something to the horizontal one.

Comment: so put a canvas instead of a stackpanel... if u want I can show you how to make user controls